# FirstOrDefault comparation with null

Tags: c#, null, compare

Can you please explain, how it can return true or false as first expression already returns true or or false? I mean why does it still need to compare with !=null

```
public static bool IsLanguageAvaliable(string lang)
    {
        return AvaliableLanguages.FirstOrDefault(languages => languages.LangCultureName.Equals(lang)) != null;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how it can return true or false as first expression already returns true or or false?

The first expression does not return true or false, your assertion is incorrect.

[FirstOrDefault()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb340482(v=vs.100).aspx)

> Returns the first element of a sequence, or a default value if the sequence contains no elements.

onto

> I mean why does it still need to compare with !=null

Since your first assumption is incorrect, and per the documentation it returns the [default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx) and the default of a class deriving from object is `null` checking equality on null means that no object exists in the sequence.

Comment: It's redundant to say "class deriving from object". All classes except object derive from object.

Comment: @EricLippert (You're awesome) yes, that statement was more about default for any object and indirectly hinting that default is not always null for other types not deriving from object.

Answer (score 4):

`FirstOrDefault` will return the default value for the type if the expression doesn't find any matches in the collection. Put another way, if no `languages.LangCultureName` is equal to the value of `lang` you will get a `null` back from `FirstOrDefault`.

While it is true that your expression `languages.LangCultureName.Equals(lang)` returns true or false, that value is used to *select an object from the collection*, it is not the return value of your method.

If all you're trying to do is determine if the `lang` exists you should use `.Any` rather than `.FirstOrDefault`.

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off using "Any", which will return true if any elements in the list match your conditions.

```
public static bool IsLanguageAvaliable(string lang)
{
    return AvaliableLanguages.Any(languages => languages.LangCultureName.Equals(lang));
}
```

Comment: Correct but you are not answering the question

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the signature of `FirstOrDefualt` method, it's an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) on `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
FirstOrDefault<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, Boolean>)
```

As you can see the second parameter is of type Func which takes an object of type T and returns `boolean`. With this Func parameter, you're defining which elements should be chosen. So `FirstOrDefault` method iterates over your list and uses your Func method to evaluate which object is eligible for it. As a result, `FirstOrDefault` will return an object of type T if it finds an element in your `IEnumerable<T>` list, otherwise the result would be `null`